# On the farm or in the farm -- which is correct?

Tags: prepositions

I am confused about the usage of preposition in this sentence: “The cow is grazing ……. the farm”. Which one is correct?

1) The cow is grazing in the farm.

2) The cow is grazing on the farm.

Comment: "On" is correct. Prepositions are notoriously idiomatic. In the future, such questions are better suited to our sister site: English Language Learners SE.

Comment: A farm is not an enclosure, so use "on". As opposed to "in the house" where a house is an enclosed area.

Comment: On EL&U: [Do you live on a farm?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238713/do-you-live-on-a-farm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to say that is:

> The cow is grazing **on** the farm.

This is simply because when talking about things situated on a farm, we always say *on the farm*. As somebody already mentioned in the comments section, prepositions in English are very idiomatic. That's just how it is always said and there is nothing you can do about it. You just learn the proper usage.

However, when we are talking about cities and towns, we usually say *in the city* or *in town*. I guess, the easiest way to understand why is think of what a farm and a city really are. A farm is just a plot of land and we think of land as being two-dimensional. And with two dimensions, we tend to use the preposition *on*. A city, on the other hand, is a three-dimensional structure: you've got high-rise apartment buildings, skyscrapers, maybe, a subway system, et cetera. With all that stuff, you need 3D space.

Comment: I suppose if you must, "on" is better than "in".  But cows don't graze **on a farm** -- they graze **out in** a pasture.

Comment: @Michael Rybkin I came across a sentence when reading _Animal Farm_. **They rolled in the dew.** I think _dew_ is everywhere on the grass, it should be 2d structure. So why not _they rolled **on** the dew_?

Comment: @preachers I think the reason is the same as how we say when we're swimming. We say we're swimming in the water. Not on the water.

Comment: @Michael Rybkin When swimming, we are surrounded by water in all sides, in other word, it's a 3d structure. In case of dew, we just get wet rather than surround by it.

Comment: @preachers When you're rolling in the dew, you are also surrounded by it. That's my reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

correct: 2) The cow is grazing **on** the farm.

It lives **in** the forest. It lives **on** the farm.

We use **on** before 'farm'.

I work **on** a farm. (NOT in a farm)

in the car, in the taxi, on the bus, on the train, on the board, on the committee, on the page, in the corner of the page